# Websphere Portal 6.1.0.3

Tags: websphere-portal

I am not able to install Websphere portal server 6.1.0.2/3 on  64 bit Windows 7 Enterprise edition. After clicking on the autolacuch of setup, nothing happens, although its is working fine for 64 bit windows-7   professional edition.

### Please provide info that it is not possible ? if yes that what else I need to do

Thanks

Comment: I can at least verify that WebSphere Portal version 6.1 is installable in Windows 7 Enterprise Edition, but it is hard to see exactly what goes wrong for you. Which file is it that you actually try to run?

Comment: I got that Daniel. I needed to change the property of  setup.exe to run on compatible mode. Once I did it , although  it gave warning but worked successfully.

Comment: Glad you got it working.

Comment: Many Thanks To you too. :-)